# I need to loop through TextBox to get the text values in asp.net c# using code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlDocUpload">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="column-pad-bottom column-pad-top">Document Title:</div>
        <div class="column-pad-bottom2"><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="fuTitle1" CssClass="form-control"/></div>
        <div class="column-pad-bottom2"><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="fuTitle2" CssClass="form-control"/></div>
        <div class="column-pad-bottom2"><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="fuTitle3" CssClass="form-control"/></div>
        <div class="column-pad-bottom2"><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="fuTitle4" CssClass="form-control"/></div>
        <div class="column-pad-bottom2"><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="fuTitle5" CssClass="form-control"/></div>
        <div class="column-pad-bottom2"><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="fuTitle6" CssClass="form-control"/></div>
        <div class="column-pad-bottom2"><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="fuTitle7" CssClass="form-control"/></div>
        <div class="column-pad-bottom2"><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="fuTitle8" CssClass="form-control"/></div>
        <div class="column-pad-bottom2"><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="fuTitle9" CssClass="form-control"/></div>
        <div class="column-pad-bottom2"><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="fuTitle10" CssClass="form-control"/></div>
        <div class="column-pad-bottom2"><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="fuTitle11" CssClass="form-control"/></div>
        <div class="column-pad-bottom2"><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="fuTitle12" CssClass="form-control"/></div>
    </div>

<H3> I tried using find controls it is always returning null </H3>



protected void btAddSection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = "C:/Users/emahou1/Desktop/testfolder";
    if (cbIsLink.Checked == true)
    {
        if (fuTitleLink.HasFile)
        {
            // it is other section has nothing to do with the 12 input tags
        }
        else
        {
            // get the link path from the text box and save it ??   
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++  )
        {
            string text = "";
            for (int t = 1; t <= 5; t++)
            {
                TextBox tb = FindControl("fuTitle" + t.ToString()) as TextBox;
                if (tb != null) text += tb.Text;
            }
            if (Request.Files[i].FileName.ToString() != "")
            {

               // here i will collect the files and the textbox values to submit them to database
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have 12 input tabs that I will use to upload files to the server, I am already looping throgh the input controls to get the files, but these text boxes i want to loop through them so I can capture the text entered by the user and use that text to rename each file being uploaded ....

Comment: this are not dynamic control

Comment: when you set breakpoints, I am assuming that you are trying to get the Textbox values after doing a Button Click? edit your question, post all of the relevant code if it's on a Button_Click event as well as the `Page_Load` method..this could be a PostBack problem would need to see how you are Invoking the code in your for loop.. also are you familiar with doing a `foreach(Control ctrl in Controls)` for example.. ?

Comment: I have edited the code - take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `FindControl` inside the panel. Something like this

```
for (int t = 1; t <= 5; t++)
{
    TextBox tb = pnlDocUpload.FindControl("fuTitle" + t.ToString()) as TextBox;
    if (tb != null) text += tb.Text + "<br>";
}
```